# Python3 - EmailMessage - excel file attachment becoming ATT00001.xlsx

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to send an email with Excel sheet(.xlsx) as attachment. When the file name **exceeds 65 characters**, the attachment becomes ATT00001.xlsx and corrupted. Is there way I can overcome this issue without limiting the number of characters in the file name ?

Below is my code, any suggestion will really help.

```
import os
import smtplib
import email
import mimetypes #For guessing MIME type based on file name extension
import logging
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.mime.text import MIMEText # for adding email body

def email_report(test_res, body_summ, report_file, table, recipients):
    """
    Email Report
    :param test_res: Test Result
    :param body_summ: Email body text
    :param report_file: Report file that needs to be attached 
    :param table: Table name for which test happened 
    :param recipients: Email recipients 
    :return: None
    """
    # Create the message
    msg = EmailMessage()

    msg['Subject'] = "Regression Test Result - %s - %s" % (table, test_res)
    msg['To'] = recipients
    msg['From'] = email.utils.formataddr(('Test', 'xyz@abc.com'))

    body_int = "Hi,\n\nPlease find Test Summary below\n\n"      
    body_sig ="\nFor more details refer attached excel."    

    # find attachment type and add to email    
    ctype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(report_file)
    filename=os.path.basename(report_file)
    if ctype is None or encoding is not None:
        ctype = 'application/octet-stream'
    maintype, subtype = ctype.split('/', 1)
    with open(report_file, 'rb') as fp:
        msg.add_attachment(fp.read(),
                            maintype=maintype,
                            subtype=subtype,
                            filename=filename)
    # add email body
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body_int + body_summ + body_sig, 'plain'))

    # Now send
    with smtplib.SMTP('localhost') as s:
         s.send_message(msg)
    logging.info("Email sent to {}".format(recipients))
```

Comment: Why not just rename and send it?

Comment: @SukumarRdjf the file name is something I generate dynamically based on some of the user inputs. If there is no other option to this issue then I have to rename the file.

Answer (score 0):

It has less to do with your code and more to do with how the Exchange server formats an email.

This happens if you tried to send a message that includes both text and attachment sections. Microsoft Exchange interprets anything after an attachment as an attachment. Maybe try adding the attachment after the body text.

---

Sources:

- https://exchange-server-guide.blogspot.com/2015/11/att00001.txt-file-fix-email-attachment-issue.html
- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/oemail-oattach/what-does-an-attachment-labeled-att-plus-some/769a6677-5f25-4de8-99ad-81f2ace8d862
- http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4981187

Comment: I tried but it is not working by changing the order, the above mentioned code works fine when the file name is less than 65 chars.

Answer (score 0):

Excel file name can be greater than 65 chars.

```
part.add_header('content-disposition', 'attachment', filename=xlsx_name)
```

demo code

```
        try:
            msg = MIMEMultipart()
            msg['From'] = email_from
            msg['To'] = email_to
            msg['Subject'] = email_sub

            html = f"""<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>{email_sub}</title> 　　
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>
  <table align="center" width="600px">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div style="margin: 20px">
          <p style="font-size: 15px">{email_msg}</p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr> 　
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div style="margin: 20px">
          <p style="font-size: 15px">详情请咨询: {email_contacts}</p>
          <p style="color:red;font-size: 14px ">这是一封自动发送的邮件，请勿回复</p>
          <label style="font-size: 15px">{_UTC_NOW.strftime(_DATE_TIME_FORMAT)}</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>"""  # noqa:E501
            msg_html = MIMEText(html, 'html', 'utf-8')
            msg.attach(msg_html)

            part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
            part.set_payload(open(file_path + "/" + xlsx_name, "rb").read())
            encoders.encode_base64(part)
            part.add_header('content-disposition', 'attachment',
                            filename=xlsx_name)
            msg.attach(part)

            with smtplib.SMTP(_EMAIL_SMTP_HOST, 587) as mail_server:
                mail_server.ehlo()
                mail_server.starttls()
                mail_server.login(email_from, _EMAIL_PASSWORD)
                mail_server.sendmail(
                    email_from,
                    email_to.split(','),
                    msg.as_string()
                )
        except Exception as e:
            logger_error(f"Email meet a exception: {str(e)}")
```